# How to type an async fetch in a function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

Given the following code, I'm receiving an unsafe assignment error for the data constant.

```
import { useQuery, QueryResult } from "react-query";
import { url } from './api';

import { User, UserFetch } from '../types/User';

const getUser = async (): Promise<User> => {
  //
  // Unsafe assignment of an any value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
  //
  const data = await fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());
  return data;
}

export default function useUser(): QueryResult<User> {
  return useQuery<User>("userData", getUser);
}
```

How can I safely type the awaited result of the data assignment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes you reach the end of type safety. This is one of those times.

There is no 'safe'  way to take what `res.json()` returns and assign it to a specific type. This is in essence a leap of faith, that the result returned from the server indeed has the shape of the `User` interface.

Disabling the rule in this case seems appropriate. You could also be more specific about the fact that you are asserting that the server returns a `User` by using an explicit type assertion (not sure if that will silent the lint rule though):

```
const getUser = async (): Promise<User> => {
  const data = (await fetch(url).then((res) => res.json())) as User;
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Explicitly asserting the type as you do in your example makes sense. TY